# obtaining a requestDispatcher

Tags: java, servlets

What is the benefit of using the servletContext as opposed the request in order to obtain a requestDispatcher?

```
servletContext.getRequestDispatcher(dispatchPath)
```

and using

```
argRequest.getRequestDispatcher(dispatchPath)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's there in the javadocs in black and white

http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)

> The difference between this method and
>   ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher(java.lang.String)
>   is that this method can take a
>   relative path.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `getRequestDispatcher` from `ServletContext`, you need to provide an absolute path, but for `ServletRequest` objects, you need to provide a relative path.